# how to get background to scroll with player height in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making an endless jumper.  I am trying to get the BG to scroll down based on the players height.

I have seen code that moves the code at a specific speed:

```
public float speed = .5f;

void Updated(){

     Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, Time.deltatime * speed);
     GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = offset;﻿
}
```

I want to move it with the height of the player.

```
 public float PlayerHeight;
```

So now I need to set the height of the BG.  I can't figure out how to do this part.

```
Transform background;
public float backgroundHeightY;
public GameObject BackGround;
```

from here I am stuck.  I don't want it to move with the camera, but move at a certain rate based on the height of the player.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Why not calculate the difference in player height between frames and then add or subtract this value to the current position of your background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally did this.  I actually switched the camera from orthographic to perspective.  It took a lot of tweaking to layout, but it ended up working perfectly well.  So the code I have above I deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a background that has a fixed position relative to the camera, but you want the background to scroll "against" the player as they move up and down, giving a parallax effect?

```
public Transform player;
public float multiplier = 0.1f; //Tweak this

void Update(){
     Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, player.position.y * multiplier);
     GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = offset;﻿
}
```

Comment: That is correct.  How do I tie this to the BG BG though?

Comment: I get this error now : Material texture property _MainTex has offset/scale set. It is incompatible with Sprite Render

Comment: You'll have to use a regular MeshRenderer (probably a Quad) if you want to use this.

Comment: Thank you I ended up changing the camera to perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working well going up, but not down.  Here is how it is working going up.  I have adjusted the backgroundModifier to fit the timing I need.

```
     //Changes the BG position
     changeAmount = (playerHeightY - currentCameraHeight)/backgroundModifier;
     Vector3 temp = new Vector3(0, changeAmount, 0);
     BackGround.transform.position += temp;
```

Anyone have an idea on how to get the falling to work.  I feel like I am making this harder than it needs to be.